# Bitcoin miner for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, bitcoin

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I was wondering if there are any good Bitcoin mining software with a GUI that is easy to understand. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: This should be asked rather at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

You can give [bitcoin-qt](https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin) a try.

Add the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
```

Update Software List

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the application

```
sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt
```

Comment: Then what?  It is downloaded.

Comment: bitcoint-qt is not mining software, but a wallet and the block index. This means at startup time it currently needs to download (in compressed form) a history of  all transactions ever conducted (currently, in 2017: 145 GB). It's a reference implementation though.